# Error 404 when "render_template" tries to load HTML page

Tags: html, flask

I have an index.html and a demo.html.  On the index page is an `<a>` tag that links to demo.html  But when that link is clicked, it returns error 404.  The pages are in the same directory, I've restarted the Flask server, made sure there's no spelling error in the link, etc.  Also looked through the similar questions asked here and checked my code against the answers and to my eyes it looks fine.  Any idea what I've done wrong here?

Index.html:

```
<a href="demo.html">Click here to drop your demo</a>
```

application.py:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("/index.html")
    

@app.route("/demo")
def demo():
    return render_template("/demo.html")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates folder is for use within the Flask application for rendering purposes like in your `index()` and `demo()` views. Creating an anchor tag that refers directly to a file located on the server instead of to a defined route that renders the template won't work unless the application defines a `static_folder` to serve files directly from.

You could move/copy the `demo.html` from the templates folder to the static folder but that's likely not what you want to do. Having the anchor tag refer to the route that renders "demo.html" is probably the behavior you're looking for.

```
<a href="/demo">Click here to drop your demo</a>

or

<a href="{{ url_for('demo') }}">Click here to drop your demo</a>
```

Comment: Just for anyone else who comes to this post later on - /demo worked, {{ url_for('demo') }} did not.  The latter returned a jinja2 error: 'demo' is undefined.  Thanks for your help and clear explanation!